# YUI .. call one javascript function from another java script

Tags: yui

I have started writing unit tests. I need to call a function in `signup.js` from another script, `unittest.js`. How can I do this?

`Unittest.html` would incorporate both scripts.

```
 <html>
 <head>

 <script scr ="signup.js"></script>
 <script src="unittest,js"></script>

</head>
</html>
```

This is `signup.js`, which I have to test.

```
YUI.use(function(Y){

    demo : function(){

        window.alert('hello);
    }

});
```

`unittest.js`:

```
YUI.use(function(Y){
 var abc = new Y.Test.case(

   testOk : function(){


      demo();                // Calling this function but not working 
     <Some_Assestion_Stuff_Here>

  }

   );


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two scripts have both created a YUI sandbox. Neither sandbox share anything with the other, so you cannot achieve unit testing `demo()` like this.

What you can do is to register a module in `signup.js` and **use** it in `unittest.js`. See the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/746nq/

In `signup.js`, create the module:

```
// Create a YUI module in signup.js.
YUI.add('signup', function (Y) {
   // Write your module code here, and make your module available on the Y
   // object if desired.
   Y.Signup = {
       demo: function () {
           window.alert("Demo!");
       }
   };
});
```

In `unittest.js`, use the module:

```
// Create a YUI sandbox in unittest.js and use our newly created module
YUI().use('signup', function (Y) {
    Y.Signup.demo();
    // assert stuff
});
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Yeah , Nice Exactly what I want .. Thanks alot .. But Does it mean that I have to change their code (signup.js) to make it module ... Is there any otherway round .. I am avoding touching their code :) .. Hopefully I am understandable :)

Comment: Developer team have already created signupjs but not like a module ... Is there any way I can turn it to module :)

Comment: Not that I know of. I think you should impose this pattern on them, since it will benefit everybody immediately.

Comment: Ok @Jonas G. Drange : Thanks :)

Comment: Hi,Well I talk to my developer team. They told me that in Signup.js we have functions like 'emailClientSideCheck()' as well as we are processing DOM Elements . So If we make signup.js as module then we cannot directly load it as it will throw an error if particular DOM element will not be present in HTML .

Comment: That is no excuse to not create a module. If it is absolutely dependant on DOM, then recreate the required DOM tree wherever you load the module. But only if the module is progressively enhancing pre-existing DOM. If not, it should create its own DOM. Do you not think so?